# List icons greyed out

Tags: list, permissions, administration

I have a site collection for which I am a Full Owner and also have an account which is the site collection admin. I can create lists, but cannot get to the list settings. I have the same problem with existing lists for which I have permission.

Another web application is working fine.

Any thoughts?

Greg

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using?

Comment: Any what browser are you using?

Comment: Do you have any custom javascript on the site? javascript errors can cause funky things to happen to the ribbon.